# How to add active class on current menu item page?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

In my Meteor app I need to add class to navigation item when page is active.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
Template.header.helpers({
  getActiveClass: function(routeName) {
    var active = Router.current() && Router.current().route.getName() === routeName;

    return active && 'active';
  }
});
```

```html
<li class="{{getActiveClass 'home'}}">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
</li>
```

Note if you want to make the element active for more than one route you have to modify the getActiveClass helper a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

Add Package `zimme:iron-router-active`

Use as follows:

`class="{{isActiveRoute regex='<route>'}}"`

For example

```
<li class="{{isActiveRoute regex='dashboard'}}">
                        <a href="{{pathFor route='dashboard'}}"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> <span
                                class="nav-label">Dashboard</span> </a>
                    </li>
```

So whenever the Route is active, Link will be Active.